# Do you need to pay any income tax on a director's loan in the UK?

Tags: income-tax, united-kingdom, loans

If there is large director's loan, say £40,000, but that amount is paid back before the deadline of 9 months past the company year end, and the interest is paid to the company at HMRC's recommended rates, are there any personal tax liabilities?